# Formal alternative to 'what are you doing here?'

Tags: phrase-request, politeness, idiom-request, formal-language

As far as I know, there *is* a fixed phrase/idiom for saying *what are you doing here?* but I have forgotten it.

It is a very formal and polite way of saying that.

*What are you doing here?* can sound impolite and even rude.

Does anyone know that phrase/idiom?

---

**Edit after [Msfolly's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/254015/106592):**

Sorry for not giving a context.

The context I had in mind was like: Suppose you saw your friend near your home and you want to know what he is doing there, so you would ask *what are you doing here?* (the meaning is literal). But there was a polite alternative to *what are you doing here?*...

Comment: Are you thinking of "Can I help you?" This can be a genuine offer to a customer in a shop, or someone approaching a reception desk, but it can also be a polite way of saying "You are not supposed to be here - what do you want?"

Comment: You need to give us more context....

Comment: If the person is a friend, it is not rude. [But is there a polite alternative to]

Comment: If the friend hadn't been invited and didn't live nearby, you might say in a surprised tone "Hello! Are you coming to see me?"

Comment: If it's a friend whose habits you know, you might say “This is out of your way!”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What brings you here?" is neutrally phrased and wouldn't be considered impolite in any scenario I can think of. I'd probably use it in a formal situation if I just wanted to know why the other person was there.

Comment: *To what do you owe the pleasure of being here* is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a fixed phrase, but perhaps you could try one of the following.

- Can I help you?
- Have you lost your way?
- Do you have permission to be here?